# Why is this pattern irrefulable?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm new to Haskell and trying to create a function that evaluates an arithmetic expression:

```
data Expr = Number Rational | Variable String | Plus Expr Expr deriving (Eq, Show , Read)

eval (Plus lhs rhs) = Number (a + b)
  where Number a = eval lhs
    Number b = eval rhs
eval x = x

main = putStrLn . show $ eval (Plus (Number 1) (Variable "x"))
```

I want the `eval` function to evaluate the expression until it hits a `Variable`, meaning whenever the two expressions within `Plus` evaluate to a `Number` you can collapse it to a new `Number`, otherwise you cannot collapse the `Plus` but maybe you can collapse only one side of the `Plus`. eg: eval (Plus (Number a) (Number b)) == Number (a + b) eval (Plus (Var "a") b) == Plus (Var "a") (eval b)

I expected the pattern `Number b` to fail and to move on to `eval x = x`
and just return the expression as is, but instead it produces an error:
`main: main.hs:5:9-27: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Main.Number b`

Why is this happening and how can I solve it ?

Comment: The pattern that has to fail for the code to move on to `eval x = x` is only `Plus lhs rhs`. Once that is matched, the code for that case will be executed (and in your case, it throws a pattern match error in the `where`).

Comment: so how should i rewrite this ?

Comment: Not at all. How do you expect this to work, what output do you want to get? How would the variable evaluate to something that you can add to a number? Should every expression evaluate to a rational number?

Comment: I want the `eval` function to evaluate the expression until it hits a variable, meaning whenever the two expressions within `Plus` evaluate to a `Number` you can collapse it to a new `Number`, otherwise you cannot collapse the `Plus` but maybe you can collapse only one side of the `Plus`.

eg: 
`eval (Plus (Number a) (Number b)) == Number (a + b)`                                     
`eval (Plus (Var "a") b) == Plus (Var "a") (eval b)`

Comment: so that `eval` boils the expression to the simplest form, it computes all that can be computed without knowing the variables, and returns a new simpler expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use a `case` expression to match all the possible outcomes of the inner `eval` calls, not just `Number`s:

```
eval (Plus lhs rhs) = case (eval lhs, eval rhs) of
  (Number a, Number b) -> Number (a + b)     -- two numbers can be summed
  (otherA,   otherB)   -> Plus otherA otherB -- other values form a Plus with collapsed parts
eval x              = x
```

Comment: Thanks! that works as I want and does not use extra compiler features like `ViewPatterns`

Comment: AN IMPROVEMENT: `Plus [Expr]` how would you do it ?

`eval Plus [(Number 1),(Number 2),(Variable "a"),(Number 3)] = Plus [(Number 6), (Variable "a")]`

Comment: I wouldn't ever write my `Plus` constructor as a list of expression exactly because that only makes it harder… rather write the function to deal with nested `Plus`es by always moving `Number`s to the top level (applying the commutative/associative laws of addition).  But have a look at `List.partition` to separate Numbers from non-Numbers. Or even better use a `fold` with a tuple of the numeric sum and a list of variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ViewPatterns` to make this relatively pretty:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
eval (Plus (eval -> Number a) (eval -> Number b)) = Number (a+b)
eval x = x
```

Given your comments, I would be remiss if I didn't point out there are some flaws with your proposed algorithm, though; for example:

```
> eval (Number 3 `Plus` Number 4 `Plus` Variable "a") -- doesn't know about associativity of Plus
Plus (Plus (Number (3 % 1)) (Number (4 % 1))) (Variable "a")
> eval (Variable "a" `Plus` (Number 3 `Plus` Number 4)) -- doesn't simplify recursively when it hits a variable
Plus (Variable "a") (Plus (Number (3 % 1)) (Number (4 % 1)))
```

Consider normalizing to a less structured type; perhaps something like

```
data Sum = Sum Rational (MultiSet String)
```

telling the sum of all the `Number`s in the first part and how often each variable appeared in [the second part](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html). Then

```
eval :: Expr -> Sum
eval (Number r) = Sum r empty
eval (Variable v) = Sum 0 (singleton v)
eval (Plus l r) = Sum (r+r') (union vs vs') where
    Sum r  vs  = eval l
    Sum r' vs' = eval r
```

Comment: The viewpattern helps at evaluating only numbers, but doesn't simplify ("collapse") other patterns. You'd need a second case `eval (Plus a b) = Plus (eval a) (eval b)`

Comment: @Bergi His original code does not do this; and I believe I point out this flaw in the answer text. I'll be more explicit about the additional failure case you discuss, though.

Comment: Thanks! your code works, and your suggestion is great for a situation with only `Plus` operations, but I intend to have all kinds of operations.

Comment: @DanielWagner  Yes (and I agree with that flaw), but it's what he says he wants in the comments. Of course that is not an `eval`uation function but rather a `simplify`cation or `normalise`tion one.

Comment: @Bergi Do you have a suggestion for improving the answer to go along with this criticism?

Comment: I realize i didn't put the code that continues the simplification for `Plus (Var a) b`, that was done to simplify the question a bit.

Comment: AN IMPROVEMENT: `Plus [Expr]` how would you do it ?

`eval Plus [(Number 1),(Number 2),(Variable "a"),(Number 3)] = Plus [(Number 6), (Variable "a")]`

Comment: @user47376 I would `instance Monoid Sum where mempty = Sum 0 empty; mappend (Sum r vs) (Sum r' vs') = Sum (r+r') (union vs vs')` and then `eval (Plus terms) = foldMap eval terms`.